# regex- test on caracters, length,vlan name :

Tags: python, regex

I dont find the command to test on vlan name :
should be between 5 and 32 characters (0-9, a-z, A-Z, can contain zero or more '/',  zero or more '-' caracter, zero or more '_' caracter and zero or more '.')
expl : Client1-192.168.1.0/24-admin_net
if vlan-name verify this --> return true

```
regexp = re.compile(r'/^[a-zA-Z0-9'.''/''_']{5,32}$/')     ??
    if regexp.search(vlan_name):
        print 'matched'
```

Comment: Try something like /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\/_]{5,32}$/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:
^[0-9a-zA-Z/_.-]{5,32}$

Comment: when you got time also test it with some other names.